# My program not going inside the delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am trying to use a delegate method in AddCity.m controller that I created in the City.m controller. The method is

City.m

```
    - (void)EditCityController:(id)controller didEditItem:(id)item
{
    if(item)
    {
        NSDictionary *d = (NSDictionary *)item;
        [self.model addNewCity:[d valueForKey:@"cityName"] forProvince:self.ro inMayor:[d valueForKey:@"mayorName"] inPopulation:[[d valueForKey:@"population"]intValue] inYearEstablished:[[d valueForKey:@"yearEstablished"]intValue]];
        [self.model saveChanges];

    }

    // Dismiss the modal view controller
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

City.h

```
    @interface Cities : 
UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, EditCityDelegate>
```

And then in AddCity.h i have

```
    @protocol EditCityDelegate;

@interface AddCity : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <EditCityDelegate> delegate;

@protocol EditCityDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) EditCityController:(id)controller didEditItem:(id)item;

@end
```

I am calling it from AddCity.m (Currently trying to the cancel button).

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate EditCityController:self didEditItem:nil];
}
```

When i put a breakpoint what happens is that it hits the self.delegate line but it does not go into the EditCityController method in the City.m controller.Any idea on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check the value of `self.delegate` there? If it's nil, Objective-C will silently skip the method call.

Comment: Nope that doesnt seem to be the problem

Comment: How did you initialize self.delegate in AddCity.m?

Comment: I'd bet that self.delegate is nil at the point of the call.  In any event, one can single-step through it, using the down arrow on the call, to see if the call goes anywhere.

Comment: It goes to the property delegate in the addcity.h file then back to the addcity.m file and finishes

Answer (score 0):

I assume you call AddCity.m in City.m and present it using presentViewController

```
AddCity *addcityVC = [AddCity new];
addcityVC.delegate = self; // initialize the delegate here
[self presentViewController:addCityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You need to initialize the delegate back to self so it can call the method you need

Hope this helps